# on click of radio button want to enable the browse option

Tags: jquery, html

i have 2 radio button and browse button which is disabled, i want to enable the browse button only when radio button is checked.

Here is what i am doing.

Please find the html below and let me know where i am going wrong or i can imporve my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <script>
      < script type = "text/javascript" >
        $("input.[name=radio2]").change(function() {
        $('input.[name=upload]').prop("disabled", false);

      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>

      <p>
      <h5><label><b>Choose option:</b></label></h5>
      <label class="radio radio--alt">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2">
        <span class="radio__input"></span>
        <span class="radio__label">XYZ</span>
      </label>
      <label class="radio radio--alt">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2">
        <span class="radio__input"></span>
        <span class="radio__label">ABC</span>
      </label>
      <br><b>
      <h4>Upload File: &nbsp <input type="file" id="uploadFile"                         name="upload" disabled="disabled"> </h4>
      </p>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using attribute selector to select the element which is right but you an extra `.` on it.

Try this

```
 $("input[name='radio2']").change(function () {
        $('input[name="upload"]').prop("disabled", false); 

    });
```

Or the easiest (class and id selector)

```
$(".radio-someclass").change(function () {
        $('#uploadFile').prop("disabled", false); 

});
```

For this to work make sure to add `radio-someclass` to both the radio element.

**Updated**

Ok wait. so you haven't used jquery, you have an extra `<script>` and put your script inside document.ready. Damn!!! lot of thing let me paste the whole thing. Please go through it properly and see what you have missed.:)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

     <head>
       <title>Page Title</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     <script>
      $(function(){
        $("input[name='radio2']").change(function() {
        $('input[name="upload"]').prop("disabled", false);

       });
      })

      </script>
      </head>

    <body>
    <form>

      <p>
      <h5><label><b>Choose option:</b></label></h5>
      <label class="radio radio--alt">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2">
        <span class="radio__input"></span>
        <span class="radio__label">XYZ</span>
      </label>
      <label class="radio radio--alt">
        <input type="radio" name="radio2">
        <span class="radio__input"></span>
        <span class="radio__label">ABC</span>
      </label>
      <br><b>
      <h4>Upload File: &nbsp <input type="file" id="uploadFile"                         name="upload" disabled="disabled"> </h4>
      </p>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am sorry but both the options not working for me..even i used id of both radio button and browse

Comment: @cool.vik updated. Recommend you to go through it properly and dont make the mistake again :) :). Helping you this time but people here in stackoverflow doesn't do this usually.

Comment: Thanks for the update and this was my first post so i may have gone wrong in mentioning my code here.. will surely take care next time..and it was silly thing i was missing...thanks again

Comment: @cool.vik cool  No problem.  Happy coding :):) . If this answer helped you or anyother answer that you might get in future, don't forget to accept the answer. ;) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work